# How to get Dreamweaver to display php gettext text?

Tags: php, dreamweaver, gettext

Is there an extension or setting that would allow Dreamweaver to actually display "Hello World" when I type `<?php echo _("Hello World"); ?>` ?

Instead it just shows a "php" icon.

I mean, I usually blend HTML and PHP together, for example:

```
<strong>We found <?php echo $results;?> results!</strong>
```

That way in Dreamweaver I can easily see the general layout and static text of a page in design mode (Dreamweaver just replaces the php codes by php icons).

However, now I need to use php 'gettext' for Internationalization. for that, I'll have to do:

```
<strong><?php echo _("We found");?> <?php echo $results;?> ...
```

So now my static text becomes php code in the eyes of Dreamwever, so it doesn't display anymore.
I was wondering if there was any extension, or something else, that would make my job easier.

Comment: do you meaning showing the whole code of php??

Comment: you don;t want to see any php icons, so that you will not be bother in seeing the code in design view? am i in the right path here?

Comment: Right path yes. It's not so that I won't be bothered, I want to see the words "We found" instead of the php icon. So that, or a web designer, can easily find his way through the page visually.

Comment: <strong>We found <?php echo $results;?> results!</strong>
you can do this. it will show

We found [phpicon] results!

in bold ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language meaning it has to go through a PHP interpreter in order for the output to be displayed, as far as I know Dreamweaver doesn't have a built-in interpreter so I doubt it's possible without further advanced configuration.

Comment: I don't need it to actually run anything, just display what's in the parentheses (like it does when you use special variables such as $_SESSION or $_REQUEST ...)

Answer (score 0):

Unless it has some sort of extension for parsing the PHP, there is absolutely no possible way for you do do what you're asking.

The only way you'll be able to see the text is by actually running the site in your web server, or having the Dreamweaver project sit in the web server folder so that when you preview the page, it'll be parsed by PHP.

In short, there's no way, within the IDE, to parse and output the results of your PHP.